# Multistage dockerfile skip stages

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I am trying to build a multistage dockerfile with following stage but all stages are getting executed.

I always c that git clone is getting executed even if I have specified `EXECUTION_ENV=local` in the docker build

**Dockerfile:**

```
ARG GIT_TOKEN=abc:1a2b3
ARG EXECUTION_ENV=local

# get dependencies from github
FROM alpine/git as gitclone-ci
WORKDIR /usr/src/
RUN git clone https://{GIT_USER_TOKEN}@github.com/something.git \
    && git clone https://{GIT_USER_TOKEN}@github.com/somethingelse.git

## in local dependencies are already available in the parent folder
FROM alpine/git as gitclone-local
WORKDIR /usr/src/
COPY ../something /usr/src/something 
COPY ../somethingelse /usr/src/somethingelse

FROM node:latest as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src
COPY --from=gitclone-${EXECUTION_ENV} /usr/src .
COPY package* ./
COPY src/ src/
RUN ["npm", "install"]
```

**Docker build cmds tried:**

```
docker build -t somecontainer --build-arg GIT_TOKEN=abc:123 --build-arg EXECUTION_ENV=local.

docker build -t somecontainer --target builder --build-arg GIT_TOKEN=abc:123 --build-arg EXECUTION_ENV=local.
```

**Note:**
If I enable `"features": { "buildkit": true}` in the docker daemon and run the cmd `docker build -t somecontainer --build-arg GIT_TOKEN=abc:123 --build-arg EXECUTION_ENV=local.` I get the following error

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to parse stage name "gitclone-$EXECUTION_ENV": invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Skipping stages only works with BuildKit. See the discussion [here](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/1134) and article [here](https://medium.com/@tonistiigi/advanced-multi-stage-build-patterns-6f741b852fae).

As for the error you're getting, you should be getting it with or without BuildKit as you cannot use build arguments in `COPY` instruction. The difference being that with BuildKit Docker will refuse to even start the build and without it the build will fail on `COPY` instruction.

What you need to do is to create an additional alias for the image you want to copy from using the fact that `FROM` instruction resolves the build args:

```
ARG GIT_TOKEN=abc:1a2b3
ARG EXECUTION_ENV=local

# get dependencies from github
FROM alpine/git as gitclone-ci
WORKDIR /usr/src/
RUN git clone https://{GIT_USER_TOKEN}@github.com/something.git \
    && git clone https://{GIT_USER_TOKEN}@github.com/somethingelse.git

## in local dependencies are already available in the parent folder
FROM alpine/git as gitclone-local
WORKDIR /usr/src/
COPY ../something /usr/src/something 
COPY ../somethingelse /usr/src/somethingelse

FROM gitclone-${EXECUTION_ENV} as intermediate

FROM node:latest as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src
COPY --from=intermediate /usr/src .
COPY package* ./
COPY src/ src/
RUN ["npm", "install"]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use build arguments in COPY instructions. You just have to specify `ARG ARG_NAME` inside of each `FROM` block it's used in.